# avoiding 500 TypeError

Tags: node.js, undefined

on node.js, suppose I have an object like this:

```
var users = {
  '1': { name: 'john' },
  '2': { name: 'jack' },
  '3': { name: 'hal' },
};
```

If I try to access `users['4'].name`, I will obviously get a `500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Totally understandable but, what about making it silent? Was it too hard for the node.js developers to implement such feature? Or am I missing some 'security' or whatever issues?

Anyway, is there an easy way to silent the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*Was it too hard for the node.js developers to implement such feature?*" Node.js doesn't maintain or change JavaScript syntax in any way. That's all managed by [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/), an implementation of [ECMA-262 or "ECMAScript"](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). To *silence* errors: `try { ... } catch(e) {}`. But, more appropriate is to check for existence, as demonstrated by dsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your code.  Instead of writing `users['4'].name`, write something like:

```
if ('4' in users)
    { users['4'].name; }
```

You need to check every condition in your code that affects your code.  The Node.js runtime can't know if you made a mistake or if you simply didn't care to actually execute some statements.

Comment: meh... this means I basically have to think of any possible situation, all the times. Guess it was too hard to do like PHP does: `$var = @$anotherVar`